# mariadb increase disk usage every day and reclaim the space when stop mariadb daemon

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My mariadb is increase disk usage every day until full the disk up. Actually data inserting to the other disk.

Only reclaim the used disk space when stop mariadb daemon.(or restart)

Mariadb is work fine until the disk full up.

Mariadb Env.

Version : 10.3.x

OS : Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Related DB Configurations.

```
| Variable_name                      | Value                    |
+------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| basedir                            | /usr                     |
| innodb_temp_data_file_path         |  ibtmp1:12M:autoextend   |
| datadir                            | /mysql_data              |
| innodb_tmpdir                      |                          |
| max_tmp_tables                     |  32                      |
| slave_load_tmpdir                  |  /mysql_data/mysql_tmp   |
| tmp_disk_table_size                |  4294967295              |
| tmp_memory_table_size              |  33554432                |
| tmp_table_size                     |  33554432                |
| tmpdir                             |  /mysql_data/mysql_tmp   |
+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

'/mysql_data' is physically separated disk with '/'.

I understand that increased '/mysql_data' disk by inserted data but don't under stand why increased every day about 2G size usage to '/' disk.

When stop mariadb daemon then reclaim the space clearly at the disk '/'.

Everyday full backup the database by mysqldump command to the '/mysql_data' disk.

Searching mariadb log but there's noting error or noticeable messages.

I think mariadb daemon is grabbed system space('/'), but don't know why.

I need your help. How can i solve this?

Comment: Why don't the `Values` line up?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I don't know how did you do that.

Comment: I'm worried that there is a non-printable character in some path.

Comment: Is the slow query log activated?